# BitBucket Pipelines and DigitalOcean permission denied

Tags: ssh, bitbucket, digital-ocean, bitbucket-pipelines

Currently getting this everytime I run my Pipeline: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Steps so far:

On Mac:

- cd ~/.ssh
- ssh-keygen -t rsa -N '' -f my_ssh_key
- base64 < my_ssh_key
- ssh-copy-id -i my_ssh_key.pub root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
- cd /my/repo/path
- ssh-keyscan -t rsa server.domain.com > my_known_hosts

On BitBucket

> Repo >> Settings >> SSH Key >> Use my own

- Pasted result of base64 < my_ssh_key into Private
- Pasted my_ssh_key.pub into Public.

Run Pipeline

> - ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ls -l /var/www
>
> Permission denied (publickey).

**pipeline.yml**

```
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
           - ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ls -l /var/www
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding your system public SSH  key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` tells your Digital ocean droplet to authorize your local machine to get acess.

You also need to add your SSH key on your Digital Ocean Account. Go to:

**Accounts > Security > Add SSH Keys**

Answer (score 1):

You may have just left it off the list of things you've done, but it looks like you haven't told Digital Ocean to authorize that public key for that user. Sign onto the DO droplet, copy the .pub file you've uploaded into ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, and try again.

Comment: How does copying the pub key authorize it for a specific user?

Comment: The tilde ( `~` ) character is shorthand in UNIX-based systems for the current user's home directory - whether that's /root or /home/user1 or something else. Since that authorized_keys file is specific to that user, connecting with that keypair will authenticate as that user.